# Error when trying to build an exe file with pyinstaller (pylibdmtx)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build an exe file.
The code imports pylibdmtx to decode data matrices. I found somewhere that this might cause issues with ctypes but i have no clue how to procede here. [Picture of the error I get when i try to start the exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaDO9.png)

Tried reinstalling everything but have no clue what to do now.

Comment: Please don't share link with pictures of the code, write it in the question, and make sure you provide a reproducibile example as well, the error is not enough

Comment: The final error message is showing that the shared library `libdmtx-64.dll` could not be found. You need to ensure that its location is added to the Windows `PATH` variable.